# Contador de tiempo en segundo plano

Tags: android, android-studio, date, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Mi idea es que la app le pida el usuario cada cuando tiempo se genere un numero aleatorio, por ejemplo cada 8 horas ¿Hay alguna función que permita que la app después de esas 8 horas genere el número aunque esta esté cerrada?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la clase [AlarmManagerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/AlarmManagerCompat)

Answer (score 0):

Hola miguel lo que pides es facil con un hilo o coroutine puede colocar un pequeñe timeOut de 8 horas como pides

Con Thread:

```
    Thread {
    while (true) {
        TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(8)
        //NUMERO RANDON
    }
}.start()
```

con coroutine:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            while (true) {
                delay(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8))
                //NUMERO RANDON
            }
        }
```

Recuerda una cosa cuando la app este en estado onPause() los hilos seguirán corriendo normal cuando destruyas la app ese hilo ya no correrá y cuando abras la app se creare un hilo nuevo

Comment: Una duda a la hora de instanciar el hilo, creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, es literalmente como lo tienes ahí? Porque el .start() me lo marca como error y con el mensaje de "Cannot resolve method .start()". Además ese código te obliga a capturar una excepción, verdad?  Muchas gracias por tu guía.